# My app keeps saying "Project1 keeps Stopping" when i try to run it in the emulator. Can't figure out why

Tags: android

Here is my code, it just keeps stopping when I go to run it and I can't figure out why.Here is the code I used in my main activity:

```
package com.example.danacarlin.project1new;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView c_img, m_img, e_img;

int count = 0;
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
TextView result_tv;
TextView count_tv;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);


    c_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    m_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    e_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    result_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
    count_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCount);


    MyOnClickListener myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();
    c_img.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
    m_img.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
    e_img.setOnClickListener(myOnClickListener);
    }
}
```

and this is MyOnClickListener Class.  Everything seems to compile properly but then when I go to run it it won't run.

```
package com.example.danacarlin.project1new;

import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by DanaCarlin on 2017-03-20.
 */

class MyOnClickListener extends Activity1 implements   View.OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1); // get a random number



    //form 1 to 3

    int count=0;
    count++;
    switch (rand) {
        /*
* rand = 1 means computer is cat, * 2 represents mouse,
* 3 represents elephant
*/
        case 1:
            imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.cat); //computer
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageView: //player choose Rock
                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Tied!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView2: //player choose Paper
                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Win!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView3: //player choose Scissors
                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Lose!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.mouse); //computer choose   mouse

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageView:
                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Lose!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView2:
                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Tie!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView3:

                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Win!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.elephant); //computer
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageView:
                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Win!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView2:
                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Lose!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
                case R.id.imageView3:
                    result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Tie!");
                    count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

I changed to Image button for imageView 1, 2,3  but left imageView4 as imageView.  But now it will go until the app starts, comes onto the screen and when I go to push the button it crashes. Here is my onclick code.

package project1.csis.pace.edu.project1;

import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by DanaCarlin on 2017-03-26.
 */

```
class MyOnClickListener extends MainActivity implements  View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
  form 1 to 3
        choose Rock
        count++;// switch (rand) { /**

        //case 1:
        imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.cat1); //computer
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cat: //player choose Rock
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Tied!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
            case R.id.mouse: //player choose Paper
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Win!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
            case R.id.elephant: //player choose Scissors
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Lose!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
        }

        //case 2:
        imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.mouse1); //computer
        //choose Paper
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cat:
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Lose!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
            case R.id.mouse:
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Tie!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
            case R.id.elephant:
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Win!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
        }
        //case 3:
        imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.elephant1); //computer
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.cat:
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Win!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
            case R.id.mouse:
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Lose!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
            case R.id.elephant:
                result_tv.setText("Result: " + "Tie!");
                count_tv.setText("Round: " + count);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your log showing the error?

Comment: Dana, why wouldn't you post the error so that we can help you?

Comment: You should definitely post the error message but another error in the above code is you cannot find a view by id until after `setContentView()` in `onCreate()` is called. So the way you are currently looking up imageView4 will cause a crash. First declare the variable and then assign it later in onCreate() like you do for all the other views.

Comment: I'm not getting an error it just goes to the emulator and says the app keeps stopping. I will try what you just said though now! Thank you!

Comment: Okay i tried changing things a little and am getting a bit further, but as soon as I go to actually click the buttons the system crashes... again no error message, it just says it keeps stopping

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

with

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: I switched it but it still did the same thing :/                                                                           @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);